# Maximum element in the array that would result from performing all M operations

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

With an array of `N` elements which are initialized to `0`. we are given a sequence of `M` operations of the sort (p; q; r). The operation (p; q; r) signifies that the integer r should be added to all array elements `A[p];A[p + 1]; : : : ;A[q]`. You are to output the maximum element in the array that would result from performing all `M` operations. There is a naive solution that simply performs all operations and then returns the maximum value, that takes `O(MN)` time. We are looking for a more efficient algorithm.

I am looking for a dynamic programming solution. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved in `O(M + N)`, trivially as follows. First, model your `Operation` like this:

```
class Operation {
    final int p;
    final int q;
    final int r;

    Operation(int p, int q, int r) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
        this.r = r;
    }
}
```

Then, create an array where you add `+op.r` at position `op.p` and `-op.r` at position `op.q + 1` for inclusive upper bounds (or `op.q` for exclusive upper bounds). This is the loop over `M`:

```
int[] array = new int[10];

Operation[] ops = {
    new Operation(1, 7, 2),
    new Operation(2, 5, 3),
    new Operation(1, 3, 1)
};

for (Operation op : ops) {
    int lo = op.p;
    int hi = op.q + 1;

    if (lo >= 0)
        array[lo] = array[lo] + op.r;

    if (hi < array.length)
        array[hi] = array[hi] - op.r;
}
```

Finally, run through the array of size `N` and find the max by cumulating each previously registered value of `+/- op.r`

```
int maxIndex = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxR = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int r = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    r = r + array[i];
    System.out.println(i + ":" + r);

    if (r > maxR) {
        maxIndex = i;
        maxR = r;
    }
}

System.out.println("---");
System.out.println(maxIndex + ":" + maxR);
```

My example yields:

```
0:0
1:3
2:6
3:6
4:5
5:5
6:2
7:2
8:0
9:0
---
2:6
```

#### Java 8 parallel version

If you have tons of cores, you can parallelise the previous algorithm using Java 8 API as such:

```
// Finally a use-case for this weird new Java 8 function!
Arrays.parallelPrefix(array, Integer::sum);
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).parallel().max());
```

This is probably faster than the previous sequential solution for very large numbers of `N` and for a sufficient number of cores.

Comment: The result must be `[0, 3, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0]`  because `q` is inclusive.

Comment: @saka1029: OK I changed my answer to yield the result you were expecting

Comment: Exception will be thrown when `op.q == 9`.

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

With the right data structures you can optimize the naive solution to run in time O(m log n + n log n). Specifically, if instead of using a raw array you use a [binary indexed tree (Fenwick tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree), you can add r to all the elements in an array between positions p and q, inclusive, in time O(log n). You can also query each element's value in time O(log n) at the end, so the total runtime would be O(m log n + n log n), significantly faster than what you have initially.

It may be possible to do even better than this. If I think of anything, I'll let you know!

Comment: Would be very curious about an actual solution implementation :) Are you sure you got complexity right? I thought things would be less than `O(N)`, when run in parallel. It should certainly be better than my solution, which runs in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly make you of segment tree. This would take O(n) space and would get the query in O(log n) time and update in O(log n). So if there are M queries on N elements, you could do it in O(M (log N)) time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate sum at all index. Simple idea for efficient solution is, Record starting and ending of each operation and integer `r` added for that operation.

Instead of going for complex data structures, simple solution is-

Suppose `arr` is the array of `N` integers initialized to zero. For each operation `(p; q; r)` update index `p & q` with `arr[p]=arr[p]+r` and `arr[q+1]=arr[q+1]-r` except last index. Some numbers in `arr` are `-ve`and some `+ve`..

Last step is iterate from first to last index, add number at each index to `current_sum`. Here `current_sum` will always be greater than zero because `p<q`, so `r` is added to `arr` before subtracted. Update `max_sum` if it is greater than `current_sum`. `max_sum` is the maximum element in the array that would result from performing all M operations.